# Converting this string to date format for saving to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, string, date

I'm moving data from a text file to a database. The text file has dates in the format 'Oct 29' and 'Nov 1' (Oct and Nov are the only 2 months in this file). I'd saving the date into a mysql database. How can I convert this format to a date field (assuming year 2012) without doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your text file, assuming the year as 2012, an array including `$array as $item['datefield']` and that you want to achieve the date translations in php alone:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
   // Format other vars...
   $insert_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item['datefield']." 2012"));

 $query_insert = "
  INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, datefield,...)
  VALUES ($item['value1'], $item['value2'], $insert_date,...)
 ";
}
```

There's little point in formatting as `yyyy-mm-dd H:m:s` as you don't have it in your datefield...

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, there may be optimisations that could be made however:

```
$date = 'Oct 29';
list($month, $day) = explode(' ',$date);
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$day $month 2012"));
```

You may be able to get away with:

```
$date = 'Oct 29';
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date 2012"));
```

Although you'd need to test the latter on which ever version of php you are running.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Oct 29';
$str = strtotime("$str " . date('Y'));
// add the currect year and convert it into Unix timestamp
$formatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$str);
// then convert it into MySQL datetime format
echo $formatted;
```